# Puedo Cargar Archivo PHP en CKEDITOR?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, ckeditor

Tengo la inquietud (necesidad en realidad) de poder cargar un archivo php dentro de CKEDITOR.
POr ejemplo, tengo un archivo php llamado contenido.php y que tiene lo siguiente:

```
$Contenido= '

<table border="0" width="500" align="center">
<tr>
    <td width="80"><img src="iconos/logo.jpg"></td>
    <td width="340" class="titulo"><center>Certificado de Recepci&oacute;n<br>de Documentos.</center></td>
    <td width="80" align="right" class="t09">N° Documento '.$ID.'</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" height="5"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" height="1" bgcolor="#dddddd"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" height="10"></td></tr>
</table>

<table border="0" width="500" align="center">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="t10" width="500">
    <br><br><br>
    <p>
    En la Ciudad de XXX, a '.$D_fecha.', el Departamento Administrativo de Educacion Municipal, certifica haber recepcionado 
    el documento N° '.$D_Num.', de tipo '.$D_tipodoc.' correspondiente a '.$D_Desc.', entregado por el Sr(a). '.$D_Emisor.', 
    en representacion de '.$D_Representa.', de la ciudad de '.$D_Ciudad.'.
    <br><br><br>
    
    Ambas partes, el Departamento Administrativo de Educacion Municipal, y el interesado, aceptan y firman este Certificado de Recepci&oacute;n de Documento.
    </p>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="250" align="center" class="t10"><u>Firma Interesado.</u></td>
    <td width="250" align="center" class="t10"><u>Firma XXX.</u></td>
</tr>
</table>';
```

Esto surge de la necesidad de poder crear un documento para cada usuario, ademas de que cada admin de cada departamento pueda modificar a su gusto dicho documento sin alterar el documento base para todos.
Existe alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Es mala idea poner todo el documento en _CKEditor_, sería mejor que solo capturen los datos que se pueden modificar y después generes el documento para visualización o impresión.

Comment: @Triby eso es precisamente lo que necesito hacer, conoces o me puedes orientar la forma de hacer o lograr eso. Saludos